# Overestimation Problem

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I had asked this problem earlier but I was too vague in how I asked it so I'm making a new post to be more specific.

> Problem: Say we have a series circuit with an ammeter, a cell with internal resistance and known emf, and a 10 ohm resistor. It is noticed that the resistor gets warmer. How would this affect the calculated value of the internal resistance?

Here is the official answer: [image]

Here is my thinking: Since the resistor increases in temperature, it increases in resistance. Let's look at the equation ℰ = IR + Ir, where "ℰ" is emf, "I" is current, "R" is external resistance, and "r" is the internal resistance of the cell. if R increases and current is constant, in order to maintain constant emf, r must decrease. Where's the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but you haven't actually listed your variables. In any question you shouuld write: it has a known emf $\epsilon$, and a 10 $\Omega$ resistor $R$. They are obvious to me here but I haven't a clue what $r$ is and that's the focus of your question.

Comment: The battery gets warmer too? That should make $r$ decrease.

Comment: I don't think it said anything about the battery getting warmer, just the 10 ohm resistor.

Comment: I'm confused about this overestimation of the r value, I don't get what the official answer is saying

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480776/2451

Comment: I thought I deleted the previous one I asked. I made this question more specific because the way I asked before was too vague.

Comment: It appears the flaw in your argument is you're assuming as R increase,  that both the current and voltage remain constant. Or possibly the current flowing through R is different from the current flowing through r - which it isn't - it's the same current..

Answer (score 0):

We measure the current of the circuit to be $I'$ where $I'$ is the current resulting from the increase in resistance caused by the increase in temperature; in other words, $I'>I$ where $I$ is the current that would arise if the resistances did not change. Thus we have

$$R+r=\frac{\epsilon}{I'}>\frac{\epsilon}{I}$$

but we *know* that $R=10 \Omega$. We measure the current of the circuit, and in that way calculate the resistances (in this case). Because we know $R=10\Omega$ we attribute the higher resistance to $r$, so it appears as though $r$ is larger than it actually is, because we are including in our value of $r$ the change in the resistance $R$ from the temperature increase. In other words, if I write the new resistance that $R$ has after the temperature increase as $R'=R+\Delta R$, then through our calculations we find that

$$r=r_{\text{actual}}+\Delta R$$

which is larger than $r_{\text{actual}}$.

Comment: wait isn't R>10Ω because the 10Ω resistor has been heated up?

Comment: I guess my main source of confusion is why would the person who is measuring the internal resistance even think that it is changing. Only the 10Ω resistor is changing resistance because only it is heating up in the circuit and nothing else. So why would the person think a lower current means a changing internal resistance when they noticed that the 10Ω resistor is heating up? Wouldn't that person connect the dots and realize the changing current is only due to the 10Ω resistor that's heating up?

Comment: In other words, why would that person think that the 10Ω resistor stays at 10Ω when that person saw it heat up.

Comment: If the person calculates a value for internal resistance that's overestimated, that person COULD NOT have known that the 10Ω resistor was ever heated up. But the problem states "it is noticed that the 10Ω resistor gets warmer"

Comment: I guess this problem is just poorly worded.

Comment: The idea is you know the resistance is 10 ohms, so when you measure the resistance of $r$, you do so by measuring the combined resistances and then subtracting the 10 ohms. Put some thought into how you'd know. Certainly we know that the resistance increases from the heat, but how do you know by how much? All you know is $R$=10 ohms. How would you otherwise know exactly what both $R$ and $r$ are if you're measuring their sum? You can't know. That's the problem you're given, you're given their sum so you have to work with the value of $R$ that you're given.